# Why is smallest compiled exe I can make with GCC is 67KB?

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, compiler-optimization

I'd like to make a very small compiled exe, which was written in C. But the smallest I can managed to get is 67KB. I'm using MinGW.
I've tried not to use any header file, and this compiles with no error:

```
//no header
void main() {
 write(1, "Hello world!", 12);
}
```

GCC shows no error if I build and run this, but it's also 67KB.

Comment: This is size before or after usage of `strip` ?

Comment: `void main` is wrong.

Comment: What do you find in the map file?

Comment: You want to have look a this interesting article: http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html This guy cuts down an `a.out` for `int main(void) { return 42; }` to 45 bytes :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314581/g-compiler-flag-to-minimize-binary-size and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771905/how-to-decrease-the-size-of-generated-binaries

Comment: Is that the file size or the size of the loaded code? You link the standard library. And enable compiler warnings; you do not declare `write`.

Comment: I'm a curious beginner, I don't know what's 'strip'. I managed to build in GCC to Notepad++, so I only get an executable. Thank's for the article, I'll read it.
Edit: This is the file size of the executable.

Comment: find out where `gcc` binary in your system, at the same diretory you find `strip.exe` use it to remove unused symbols

Comment: The Compiler will always put some bootstrapping and error handling no  into your executable

Comment: Try `int main(void) { return 0; }`

Comment: Just tried -Os and strip, now the file size is 41KB. That's something, but not too much.

Comment: Try this `gcc  -Os -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fipa-pta test.c -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--strip-all` what size does it gives?

Comment: Try this `int main;` under gcc 5.1.1 compiles flawlessly ;) Size: 8456, GNU/Linux 64-bit

Comment: I'm using Windows 7, MinGW.
`int main;`
`int main(void) { return 0; }`
These are also 41KB with -Os -s. The long parameter list by user1034749 doesn't make it smaller.

Comment: The gcc / GNU ld developers don't put much time into curiosities... they focus their development time on correct and fast output. By all means submit a gcc patch with a new switch for small "hello world" if you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reducing GCC target EXE code size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547233/reducing-gcc-target-exe-code-size)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just tried this in x86_64 Linux, which probably isn't much different to MinGW at this level, although you never know.

Basically, the problem is that, even though nothing gets pulled in from the C library unless it's referenced, the CRT "startfiles" do reference a small selection of things, which in turn reference some other things, and "Hello world" ends up looking bad. This is *not a problem worth fixing* because all real programs would reference those core functions anyway.

The source for the start files is available, and quite small, and the compiler allows you to override the standard ones if you choose to, so optimizing them is not a massive deal. They're written in assembler code, but you can probably remove most of the extraneous garbage by simply deleting lines.

But, there's a hack for cutting the start-files out of the equation altogether:

```
#include <unistd.h>

void _start (void) {
  write(1,"Hello world!", 12);
  _exit(0);
}
```

Compile: `gcc -nostartfiles t.c -s -static`

Which works (by chance, see below), and gives me a file size of **1792 bytes**.

For comparison, your original codes gives 738624 bytes, with the same compiler, which drops to 4400 bytes when I remove `-static`, but then that's cheating! (My code actually gets *larger* without `-static`, because the dynamic linker meta-data outweighs to code of `write` and `_exit`).

The *by chance* part, is that the program now has **no stack pointer** initialized. Likewise for all other global state the start-files usually take care of. As it happens, on x86_64 Linux, this isn't a fatal problem (just don't do it in production, right?) However, when I tried it with `-m32` I get a segmentation fault inside `write`.

The problem can be fixed by adding your own initialization for that stuff, but then the code would no longer be *as* portable (it isn't absolutely portable already). Alternatively, call the write system call directly.

Comment: Stack pointer not initialized? ELF files don't specify stack size or location AFAIK, so there must be a default stack set up by the system/loader. It must be something specific to gcc/glibc (something to do with extra initialization, red zone or alignment). My compiler produces executable 32-bit ELF files, which work on Ubuntu just fine without any special handling of the stack (other than accessing argc/argv; and brk works too) and invoking system calls directly (I have my own static library).

Comment: Yes, the CRT start files are responsible for setting the stack pointer (at least, on some OS/arch combinations), zeroing the BSS (again, not necessary everywhere), calling C++ static initializers, setting up atexit handlers, and whatever else the OS doesn't do. If you bypass them as I described then you don't get any of that, and whether it works or not depends on the virtual memory layout/accessibility and maybe a little luck.

Comment: Oh, and it's the CRT startfiles that call `main`. Mustn't forget to do that. ;-)

Comment: If you don't use `-static` then the dynamic linker gets run first, so the rules are a bit different, but the CRT files still do some stuff and call `main`.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old question, but I had same issue. Big size is also result of enabled by default RELRO and default max-page-size of 64K.

Hello world compiled with `gcc -Wl,-z,max-page-size=0x1000 -s -Wl,-z,norelro main.c && sstrip -z a.out` results in 2K binary.

Empty _start function file compiled with `gcc -nostartfiles start.c -Wl,-z,max-page-size=0x1000,-z,norelro && sstrip -z a.out` results in 164 bytes binary.

After some experimenting I made same program, but smaller:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
static const char str[] = "Hello world!";
void _start(){
syscall(SYS_write, 1, str, 12);
syscall(SYS_exit, 0);
}
```

With `gcc -nostartfiles start.c -Wl,-z,max-page-size=0x1000,-z,norelro -static -Os && sstrip -z a.out` resulting binary is 353 bytes on ARM. After adding `-mthumb` it becomes 349 bytes.

If you go full assembly, then you'll get 144 bytes executable. Same command line, but with .S file instead.

```
#include <sys/syscall.h>

.global _start
_start:
mov r7, $SYS_write                                 mov r0, $1
add r1, pc, $(hw - . - 8)
mov r2, $(end - hw)
svc #0
mov r7, $SYS_exit
svc #0

hw:
.ascii "Hello world!\n"
end:
.align 4
```